# What is the highest possible profile level?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

What is the highest Steam profile level? I've seen people with levels like 142 and they still have a next level indicator on their profile. Is there an end to this?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no *planned* hardcap. There's probably just a technical restriction, for the size of the value (powers of two).

Comment: http://steamcommunity.com/id/palmdesert he just keeps going and going

Comment: Assuming no imposed restriction (Valve tends to err toward "unlimited") and data storage restriction aside, there is a lower calculable limit imposed by limited experience available. #ofGamesWithCards(keeps changing)*maxXPPerGameWithCards(600) + maxAmountForNonGameBadges(sale badges, events, and game ownership - changes as stuff is added) = maxXP. Using that with the formula for XPPerLevel, we can determine the current max level. As things are added, this will constantly change so the best we can do is provide a formula or state an imposed max, if any.

Comment: I bet you could make that an answer.

Comment: @user1306322 Agreed, but I'll leave that as an exercise for a user with more time than I have at present. If it isn't done in a few hours, I should be available to do it then. This would mostly involve researching formulas and maximums for all non-game badges. Things like years of service change as you've been a Steam user for longer. Keeping it up to date as Valve is constantly adding and changing this stuff seems like a pain, so I'd probably just make it a community wiki in the end anyways.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There are 3 possible maximum levels:

- An imposed maximum by Valve would cut off leveling. Thus far, Valve has not specified any imposed maximum. Based on questions I've asked Steam Support, they are very clear about what has imposed maximums(friends list) and generally don't say anything about what does not (wish list) unless directly asked. **It seems likely, based on the evidence available, that there is no imposed maximum on Steam Levels or XP.**
- A maximum due to technical limitations such as memory capacity allocated to store a value and/or to display a value. Because levels and XP never go negative, it is likely stored in a whole unsigned value such as an integer. An unsigned integer can hold 2^32 − 1 values so 4,294,967,295 would be the maximum amount of XP that is able to be stored in a 32-bit integer. **Using some math, we end up with enough XP available to reach level 29306 with the values that can be represented in a 32-bit integer so that is the likely technical maximum unless they used a 64-bit integer.**
- A practical maximum is a restriction on what is achievable with the resources available. **Obviously as Steam gets new badges, cards, and other resources, and as badge values change, these numbers will fluctuate.** Referencing various steam accounts and other information to determine Game collector badge values and [this handy chart](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=145997931) in addition to those accounts for the others. Here are the resources available:

> ***Years of Service Badge XP:*** Steam was started September 12, 2003 and this badge grants 1 level worth 50 XP per year of service so the maximum at this point in time is level 10 and therefore ***500 XP***.
>
> ***Game Collector Badge XP:*** Steam search data is very unreliable in general and determining what games count is very difficult. Steam search lists a total of [2583](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?sort_by=Price&sort_order=DESC&category1=998&page=88) "games" available, but some aren't actually games, some are duplicated and some are missing from the results. It's unclear what counts towards the badge anyways. Without more information, [2410](http://steamcommunity.com/id/palmdesert) are confirmed to count towards the badge - close enough to search results until a better determinate is found. All badges above 250 grant 250+#ofGames XP so ***2660 XP***
>
> ***Trading Card Badge XP:*** Each regular trading card set provides for up to 5 levels, each worth 100 XP per regular badge, and 1 level worth 100 XP per foil badge, meaning each set of trading cards is worth 600 XP. Steam search is unreliable to determine which games have trading cards because of the same problems above and the addition of unreleased items for which trading cards cannot be collected. Sorting by date filters out Wake, Lunnye Devitsy, and Dead Island. Even worse, not all games with Steam trading cards appear properly with Steam's search filters as Age of Empires II HD, Age of Empires III Complete Collection, Call of Duty: Black Ops 2 (has 2 badge sets - Multiplayer and Zombies), Call of Duty: Ghosts, Cortex Command, Jagged Alliance: Back in Action, Eversion, Mabinogi, Metal Drift, No More Room in Hell, Offspring Fling!, RIFT, Satazius, Sequence, Stacking, Street Fighter X Tekken, Talisman Prologue and maybe more are not properly pulling up in the trading card category, despite having trading cards. There's also the addition of the software RPG Maker VX Ace which also has trading cards. The formula works out to something like:
>
> ([#ofGamesWithTradingCardsOrderedByDate](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?sort_by=Released&sort_order=DESC&category1=998&category2=29) - [#ofEarlyAccessGamesWithTradingCardsOrderedByDate](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?sort_by=Released&sort_order=DESC&category1=998&category2=29&genre=Early+Access) + [#ofEarlyAccessGamesWithTradingCards](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?category1=998&category2=29&genre=Early+Access) + #ofGamesErroneouslyFilteredByDate + #ofSetsMissingFromTradingCardCategory + [#ofSofwareWithTradingCards](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?category1=994&category2=29) + #ofSaleBadgesFollowingRegularTradingCardLevelRestrictions) x 600.
>
> Filling in the above for the current known values, we get (467 - 26 + 31 + 3 + 19 + 1 + 1(Steam Summer Getaway)) x 600 = **297600 XP**
>
> *as Black Ops 2 already has 2 sets and there has been mention of more series of cards to come, it seems likely that this calculation will become much more difficult.*
>
> ***Holiday Sale 2013 Trading Card Badge XP:*** This trading card badge and foil exceeded normal trading card crafting limitations with no maximum level. In theory, it could have been possible to reach levels into the millions were money and time no object, but the practicality of it is that the known maximums reached were [2013 for the regular and 100 for foil](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3211086) to a maximum of **211300 XP**
>
> ***Community Ambassador Badge XP:*** With a maximum level of 2, with each level worth 100 XP, this offers **200 XP**.
>
> ***Trading Card Beta Badge XP:*** Is worth **100 XP**
>
> ***Steam Community Translator Badge XP:*** is worth **100 XP**
>
> ***Steam Hardware Beta Candidate Badge XP:*** is worth **150 XP**
>
> ***Steamworks Community Developer Badge XP:*** is worth **500 XP**
>
> ***Steam Community Moderator Badge XP:*** is worth **500 XP**
>
> ***Valve Employee Badge XP:*** is worth **1000 XP**
>
> ***Steam Holiday Sale 2012 Badge XP:*** is worth a maximum of **100 XP**. Value per task is used here.
>
> ***Steam Summer Sale 2012 Badge XP:*** is worth a maximum of **100 XP**. Value per task is used here.
>
> ***Steam Holiday Sale 2011 Badge XP:*** is worth a maximum of **200 XP**. Value per task is used here.
>
> ***Steam Summer Camp Badge XP:*** is worth a maximum of **200 XP**. Value per task is used here.
>
> ***The Potato Sack Badge XP:*** is worth a maximum of **200 XP**. Value per task is used here.
>
> ***The Great Steam Treasure Hunt Badge XP:*** is worth a maximum of **100 XP**. Value per task is used here.
>
> ---
>
> This gives us a current grand total of 500+2660+297600+211300 +200*4+100*5+150+500*2+1000 = 
>   **515510 XP**
>
> This is probably the long way to calculate it, but using the arithmetic progression formula for every 10 levels to determine the number of times the experience required for the first 10 levels (1000) needs to be multiplied, taking a look at level 310 (based on where palmdesert's level + some trial and error) gives us (31/2)*(2+(31-1)) = 496 and 496 * 1000 XP = 496000 XP required to get to level 310 and each level after that cost 3200. This leaves us at level 310 with 19510 XP remaining. 19510/3200 = 6 r310, meaning level 316 is the maximum that gives us.

The practical maximum is somewhere around level 316. Valve employees are unlikely to have many of the community participation badges, etc. so not being a Valve employee is likely to net more points in reality. This means 1000 less from what's available and leaves the total available XP just under the threshold for level 316, meaning that **the current practical maximum Steam level is probably about 315**.

Steam search data inconsistencies make it impossible to be sure how much higher a level can actually be reached because there is no reasonable or consistent way to determine which items are being incorrectly added to or removed from the result sets. Given the unbounded nature of the Holiday 2013 trading card badge, it is entirely possible that an actual maximum level could have been reached, but that is simply impractical.

Comment: What would also be interesting - how much would it cost to buy your way to level 149.

Comment: @5pike Since most of the XP comes from the card badges, you'd clearly have to. Unlike keeping this up to date which might be a daily thing at most, an answer on price is nigh impossible because prices fluctuate by the second and there are other ways to get cards such as drops, trades and boosters which make it even worse to calculate accurately. I'd say just watch several prices and pick them up at the lowest. Try to do profitable trades when you can and use boosters in the most profitable way for your current card collection.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Would be a very hard and time-consuming task and the outcome wouldn't be very accurate. Still, an estimate would be interesting.

Comment: @5pike: As a ballpark calculation: Assuming an average of €0.15 for a single card, €1 for a foil card, and 7.5 cards per badge, this would put the total cost at ~€13.12 for level 5 + foil per game, ending up at just under €2500 for all 190 games, assuming you buy all of your cards. Actually, the actual cost may very well be *higher*, since at least some games (mostly the less popular ones) seem to have significantly more expensive cards (especially foils) - but it will of course depend on drops, boosters and trades. (It also ignores the cost of getting the games in the first place.)

Comment: In the original answer, I forgot about Steam's tendency to list multiple versions of the same items, incorrectly categorized items, and, worst of all, unreleased items. I have updated the answer to reflect the new numbers.

Comment: It also might be good to emphasize how much this is likely to change due to new cards being added often.

Comment: @Ullallulloo That emphasis seems undue. It's been discussed in multiple comments on this question and should be obvious. I will take it under advisement, but if you're referring to my previous comment, I was speaking specifically to Steam's search functionality which gives inconsistent results and has many items with flawed data. Since the answer is largely based on  those search results for cards numbers, I had to change the link(s) and math for the cards available because the previous results were too high (inclusion of unreleased games) and too low (omission due to erroneous data).

Comment: @skovacs1: No, I was just saying by itself. While this answer does imply that it will change, the casual reader in a couple months might get the wrong idea.

Comment: You obviously went all-out with this answer.

Comment: @skovacs1 Thank you for the work on this answer, but updating it over and over seems... futile.

Comment: @BlaXpirit I'd love to leave a general formula, but it is highly dependent upon Steam search functionality. Steam's search data is plagued by inconsistencies. I notified them, they merged my cases into one and told me they would forward the information to the appropriate department. As of yet, corrections have not been made and my case sits open. When the trading card badge XP is no longer a growing list of exceptions and things that don't work, the formula would be clear and reliable. I decided to wait a few months for them in order to give the best answer possible, meanwhile meaning updates.

Comment: According to http://store.steampowered.com/promotion/snowglobefaq, "During the sale there is no limit to the number of times you can upgrade these badges", i.e. by spending enough money you seem to be able to obtain as much XP as you want by buying snow globes until Jan 2...

Comment: palmdesert is currently level 221 and has the [snow globe foil badge on level 100](http://steamcommunity.com/id/palmdesert/gamecards/267420?border=1) so that's probably the actual limit...

Comment: http://www.steamcardexchange.net/index.php?showcase seems to have a fairly complete list of trading cards. This may be a better way to determine available trading card badges. I will investigate its accuracy and easy of counting at a later date.

Comment: Note that your second dot point can be mitigated depending on how they store XP. If instead of having a single 'XP' value with your 'level' calculated off of it, they could instead had a 'Level' value and a 'current XP' value. When you level up they could reset the current XP to 0 and increment your level counter, maxing the maximum *level* effectively the max `unsigned long` (4,294,967,295 as you mention)